# Programmatic filtering RadGridView

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik

Let's say that in my db, in a column named **UserName**, i have this value **Jean-Andrew Pierre**. I have a problem with creating the filter for retrieving this value from db, when i'm typing **Andrew Jean Pierre**. As you see, the order of names, are different and some characters are missing.

I've tried this:

```
var operatorNameFilter = radGridView.Columns[nameof(Username)].ColumnFilterDescriptor;
   if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(username))
   {
       operatorNameFilter.Clear();
       return;
   }

    allOperatorsName = Regex.Split(username, @"\W+");
       foreach (var name in allOperatorsName)
             operatorNameFilter.DistinctFilter.AddDistinctValue(name);

       operatorNameFilter.FieldFilter.Filter1.Operator = FilterOperator.Contains;
       operatorNameFilter.FieldFilter.Filter1.LogicalOperator = FilterCompositionLogicalOperator.And;
       operatorNameFilter.FieldFilter.Filter1.Value = username;
```

I believe the last line has to be removed, but with or without, nothing happen

Thanks,
Andreea

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer after few more tries:

```
        private void FilterByOperatorNames(RadGridView radGridView)
        {
            var operatorNameFilter = radGridView.Columns[nameof(Username)].ColumnFilterDescriptor;
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(username))
            {
                operatorNameFilter.Clear();
                return;
            }

            var allOperatorNames = Regex.Split(username, @"\W+");
            var userNamesCompositeFilter = new CompositeFilterDescriptor();
            foreach (var name in allOperatorNames)
            {
                var filterDescriptor = new FilterDescriptor(nameof(Username), FilterOperator.Contains, name);
                userNamesCompositeFilter.FilterDescriptors.Add(filterDescriptor);
            }
            userNamesCompositeFilter.LogicalOperator = FilterCompositionLogicalOperator.And;
            radGridView.FilterDescriptors.Add(userNamesCompositeFilter);
        }
```

I hope to help others.